# What is the relationship between periodic points and invariant points?

Tags: dynamical-systems

What is the relationship between periodic points and invariant points?

Is every periodic points an invariant point?

Comment: Could you say more about the context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A periodic point is a point $p$ such that $f^m(p)=p$ for some (smallest) integer $m \geq 1$. If $m=1$, it is an invariant point (more commonly called a fixed point).

So every fixed point is a periodic point, but the converse is not true.

Comment: Is there an example that shows the converse is not true?

Comment: sure, take $f(z)=-z$: then $p=1$ is a periodic point of period 2 since $f(1)=-1 \neq 1$ and $f(f(1))=-(-1))=1$.